# Can I use a single vector which has three element to represent three axis of a object?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm a programmer and are dealing with Euler angles. 
In Euler angles system, only a vector of x,y,z (3 numbers) can represent any rotation, and I can use them to calculate the "front axis", "up axis", and "right axis".

But if I do not use Euler angles system, but pure vectors, I need at least two vectors(the third one can be  calculated by the former two), which are 6 numbers.

So can I use a single vector to represent my three axis(For memory saving)? Or,Are there any implicit facts which allow Euler angles system to only use 3 numbers?

Comment: So do you want to rotate an object, and so you want to store by how much (and which direction) to rotate?

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev yes, I think so.

Comment: Do you rotate the object around its axis?

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev, I thinks so, it is a camera object, I think in a fps game it will rotate itself around its axis.

Answer (score 2):

If you use vectors - you'll need 3 of them to represent bases of 3D space. 2 vectors will form a *plane* in 3D. So if you want to represent a rotation with a matrix, you'll need a 3x3 matrix.

As far as I understand in order to speed up calculations (maybe for other reasons too) people split 3x3 matrix into 3 Basic rotations (you can read about them on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)). This way you keep your original vector (or align it to one of the axises and keep its length), then multiply it by these 3 basic matrices to get the transformed vector. After that if you turn camera around 1 axis you replace one of the matrices (representing that rotation) with the new one and multiply again.

These probably will be useful resources:

- [Euler Rotations Simplified: Deriving the Rotation Matrices](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOc-l7Vp__E)
- [Linear Algebra by 3b1b](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab)
- [Rotations by lem.ma](https://www.lem.ma/content/DEGG_oP0YCjLKBDhwUxfKQ)
- [Game Dev SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

There's another branch of math that can be used for 3D transformations: [Quaternions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d4EgbgTm0Bg). They use 4 values which not only describe the where to rotate, but also how to get there (clockwise/anti-clockwise).

Also, mind [Gimbal lock](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zc8b2Jo7mno).

PS: use my advice with caution since I'm not experienced in any of this.

PPS: Seems like the OP got some good answers at GameDev SE: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/183358

Answer (score 0):

welcome to MSE. First off, with geometry it’s helpful to include a diagram, because there might be multiple similar definitions. Your 2nd method isn’t very well stated. However, in this case I think I know what you’re talking about.

Your problem: to represent a rotation in 3D-space.

Your method 1: represent with 3 Euler angles.

Your method 2: represent with two vectors u, v, where u = image of x axis, v = image of y axis.

In the 2nd method, suppose you determine u first. Then it has only two degrees of freedom (because it has norm 1, which fixes the third component).

Then, v actually only has one degree of freedom, because it has to also be perpendicular to u.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Sorry for lacking some math terms, does that mean if I use method 2, I have to use at least two vectors?